# Bootstrap dialog aligning the title to the right

Tags: css, html, bootstrap-modal

For some reason the bootstrap dialog is aligning the title to the right.
I tried to modify the class modal-title, tried to create another class "forcing" to align the text to the left without success.

The code as follows:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modal_editor" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">

    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content largemodal">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Editor</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body" id="content">
                <iframe src="Editor.aspx" width="750" height="470"></iframe>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated it!

Comment: The problem isn't your modal-title -- you've placed the title after the close button element, which is, by default, right-justified. Move the h4 before the button, and you should be fine.

Comment: Snowmoneky, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the issue is in **where** is you modal-title.

switch the order like this.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modal_editor" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">

    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content largemodal">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title">Editor</h4>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body" id="content">
                <iframe src="Editor.aspx" width="750" height="470"></iframe>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and that's it.